# "Invalid Character" in SQL query string (ORA-00911)

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I'm attempting to setup a small application to pull data on a weekly basis. I created the PL/SQL query itself in TOAD and it executes fine there when run manually. From there I wrote the following script for my VB application:

```
Private Sub MainWin_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    '
    Dim QTxt As String = ""
    Dim ConStr As String = "Data Source=b;User Id=my_user_name;Password=some_pass;"
    Dim scon As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConStr)
    Dim d As New DataStore
    Dim scmd As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
    Dim odr As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader

    Me.Status.Text = Now() & " - Building the SQL executor"
    Me.Refresh()
    'Build the query executor
    Try
        scmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        scmd.Connection = scon
        'Format 1 for the PL/SQL query language taken from TOAD (SINGLE LINE FORMART)
        'QTxt = "select case   when (userhost like 'uss-09%' and userid in ('A', 'ASYSPUB')) then 'B'   when userid like 'NOE%' then 'Noe'   when ((userhost like  'uss01%' or userhost like 'uss02%') and userid in ('A','ASYSPUB')) then 'F'   when ((userid like '%_IU%' or userid like 'RPT%' or userid in ('EFRW', 'EMOPOR', 'EM_IU')) and userhost <> 'uss%') then 'I'   else 'Other'  end app_type, round(sum(sessioncpu/100), 1)  cpu_seconds, (sum(sessioncpu/100)/(119*1*60*60)*100) pct_of_cpu, trunc(nts#,'MI') RunDate from PSTAT.AUD$_A where nts# >= ((trunc(SYSDATE)-9))  and nts# < (trunc(SYSDATE)-2)  and l$t < (trunc(SYSDATE)-2) group by  case  when (userhost like 'uss-09%' and userid in ('A', 'ASYSPUB')) then 'B'  when userid like 'NOE%' then 'Noe'  when ((userhost like 'uss01%' or userhost like 'uss02%' ) and userid in ('A','ASYSPUB')) then 'F'  when ((userid like '%_IU%' or userid like 'RPT%' or userid in ('EFRW', 'EMOPOR', 'EM_IU')) and userhost <> 'uss%') then 'I'  else 'Other'  end, trunc(nts#,'MI') order by trunc(nts#,'MI'),1;"

        'Format 2 for the PL/SQL query language taken from TOAD (Wrapped as in TOAD)
        '            QTxt = "select case" & Chr(10) & _
        '        "when (userhost like 'uss-9%' and userid in ('A', 'ASYSPUB')) then 'B'" & Chr(10) & _
        '        "when userid like 'NOE%' then 'Noe'" & Chr(10) & _
        '        "when ((userhost like  'usst01%' or userhost like 'uss02%' ) and userid in ('A','ASYSPUB')) then 'F'" & Chr(10) & _
        '        "when ((userid like '%_IU%' or userid like 'RPT%' or userid in ('EFRW', 'EMOPOR', 'EM_IU')) and userhost <> 'uss%') then 'I'" & Chr(10) & _
        '        "else 'Other'" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "end app_type, round(sum(sessioncpu/100), 1)  cpu_seconds, (sum(sessioncpu/100)/(119*1*60*60)*100) pct_of_cpu, trunc(nts#,'MI') RunDate" & Chr(10) & _
        '"from PSTAT.AUD$_A" & Chr(10) & _
        '            "where nts# >= ((trunc(SYSDATE) - 9))" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "and nts# < (trunc(SYSDATE)-2)" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "and l$t < (trunc(SYSDATE)-2)" & Chr(10) & _
        '            "group by" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "case" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "when (userhost like 'uss-09%' and userid in ('A', 'ASYSPUB')) then 'B'" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "when userid like 'NOE%' then 'Noe'" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "when ((userhost like  'uss01%' or userhost like 'uss02%' ) and userid in ('A','ASYSPUB')) then 'F'" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "when ((userid like '%_IU%' or userid like 'RPT%' or userid in ('EFRW', 'EMOPOR', 'EM_IU')) and userhost <> 'uss%') then 'I'" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "else 'Other'" & Chr(10) & _
        '    "end, trunc(nts#,'MI') order by trunc(nts#,'MI'),1;"

        'FORMAT 3 for PL/SQL taken form TOAD (CASE STATEMENT REMOVED *** WILL NEED TO REWORK AS IN CODE LOGIC ***)
        QTxt = "SELECT userhost, userid, round(sum(sessioncpu/100), 1)  cpu_seconds, (sum(sessioncpu/100)/(119*1*60*60)*100) pct_of_cpu, trunc(nts#,'MI') RunDate " & _
            "From PSTAT.AUD$_A " & _
            "WHERE nts# >= ((trunc(SYSDATE) - 9)) " & _
            "   AND nts# < (trunc(SYSDATE)-2) " & _
            "   AND l$t < (trunc(SYSDATE)-2) " & _
            "GROUP BY trunc(nts#, 'MI') " & _
            "ORDER BY trunc(nts#, 'MI'), 1;"

        'Format 4 - SINGLE LINE WITH CASE STATEMENT REMOVED
        'QTxt = "SELECT userhost, userid, round(sum(sessioncpu/100), 1) cpu_seconds, (sum(sessioncpu/100)/(119*1*60*60)*100) pct_cpu, trunc(nts#, 'MI') RunDate FROM PSTAT.AUD$_A WHERE nts# >= (trunc(SYSDATE) - 9) AND nts# < (trunc(SYSDATE) - 2) AND logoff$time < (trunc(SYSDATE) - 2) GROUP BY trunc(nts#, 'MI') ORDER BY trunc(nts#, 'MI'), 1;"
        scmd.CommandText = QTxt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Errors.Text = "An error occurred while building the SQL Executor. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Me.ProgBar.Step = 5
    Me.ProgBar.PerformStep()
    Me.Status.Text = Now() & " - Connecting to the database" & Chr(10) & Me.Status.Text
    Me.Refresh()
    Try
        'Open the connection
        scon.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Errors.Text = "An error occurred while opening the SQL connection. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Me.ProgBar.PerformStep()
    Me.Refresh()
    Me.Status.Text = Now() & " - Executing SQL statement and collecting results" & Chr(10) & Me.Status.Text
    'Use the reader to get the sql results
    Try
        odr = scmd.ExecuteReader
        If Not (TableFill(odr, d)) Then
            '    'Already captured the error at the point it occured, just clean up
            scmd.CommandText = Nothing
            scmd.Connection = Nothing
            scmd = Nothing
            odr = Nothing
            scon.Close()
            scon = Nothing
        End If 'else allow the macro to proceed

    Catch ex As Exception 'THIS IS THE CATCH THAT THE ERROR GOES THROUGH

        Me.Errors.Text = "Encountered an error while executing the query and capturing its results. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
        Me.Errors.Text = Me.Errors.Text & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & QTxt
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    'Pass the SQL Reader to the Excel Module to create the XLSX
    Me.ProgBar.Step = 15
    Me.ProgBar.PerformStep()
    Me.Status.Text = Now() & " - Exporting the resultant data to an Excel file." & Chr(10) & Me.Status.Text
    Me.Refresh()
    Try
        If TableRO(d) Then
            Me.Status.Text = Now() & " - Successfully exported the query results. Please review any logged errors and then close this window." & Chr(10) & Me.Status.Text
            Me.ProgBar.Width = 100
        Else
            Me.Status.Text = Now() & " - Failed to export the query results. Please review the logged errors for further details." & Chr(10) & Me.Status.Text
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Errors.Text = "Encountered an error while reading out the SQL results. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
    End Try

    'Clean up
    Try
        scmd.CommandText = Nothing
        scmd.Connection = Nothing
        scmd = Nothing
        scon = Nothing
        odr = Nothing
        scon.Close()
        d.DT.Clear()
        d = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Errors.Text = "Encountered an error while cleaning up varibles. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
    End Try
End Sub
```

As you can see from the code I've tried several versions of the query language, but they all return ORA00911. I've checked for formatted single quotes in each of the cases, which is the only suggestion I've seen online that could have applied to my situation.

If anyone can point out what character(s) are causing trouble it would be much appreciated.

NOTE: For the record my dream scenario is that Format 2 is the one that makes it into use, much easier to read than Format 1 (which is otherwise the same code), and doesn't require extra VB processing like Formats 3 & 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update your code to print out the text of the query string "QTxt".  Then paste that into Toad and see if it still raises the error.  Also, paste it here.

Comment: Or make it a Stored Procedure

Comment: Also.... you don't actually need the Chr(10) unless you are displaying the script somewhere.

Comment: The returned Qtxt won't fit in comment so i'll add it as an "answer" below, but it did execute in TOAD just fine.

Comment: Added the Chr(10) when I started outputing Qtxt if there was an error executing the query so that it would display nicely in the Rich Text Field I'm posting any errors to.

Comment: I'd expect the semicolons at the end of each of the query variants to be responsible. Drop them.

Comment: Just to clarify some terminology: there is nothing PL/SQL here, you're just trying to execute a plain SQL query in an Oracle database from VB.NET.

Comment: Start with small: try to execute `select 1 from dual;` from your VB code first.

Comment: Taking out the semicolon fixed it.

Comment: @collapsar Add it as an answer since it solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Collapsar is correct in the comments

"I'd expect the semicolons at the end of each of the query variants to be responsible. Drop them. – collapsar Feb 24 '15 at 23:44"

This completely solved my dynamic SQL problem from vb.net for 'Invalid Character'.  Thanks!