# "Arithmetic" operation results in an overflow

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I'm attempting to copy some information returned from a SQL query my application runs to a DataTable for some post processing and then output to a flat file.

To do this I've tried using an OracleDataAdapter as well as an OracleDataReader. Both run into an issue with the third of four values returned by the query. This value is the % of the CPU used by a job on the server. Typically it returns a value less than 0.1. I've set the relevant column of the DataTable to Double, but when I try to populate that column for a row I am told that an "Arithmetic operation results in an overflow".

This makes no sense A) because it's a straight set `dr.Item(c) = odr.Item(c)` (dr is the row of the table I'm populating and odr is the datareader). No math at all there; B) I receive that error even when I try to just cast the value to a String so that I can see what it is and try to figure out the issue based on that. Last I checked casting to String wasn't arithmetic.

The SQL that generates the value is:
`(sum(sessioncpu/100)/(119*1*60*60)*100) pct_of_cpu`

This doesn't cause an error when executing the SQL and returns fine via Toad.

Full code for the query step is [here (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698761/invalid-character-in-sql-query-string-ora-00911). The TableFill function follows:

```vb
Public Function TableFill(ByVal odr As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader, ByVal d As DataStore) As Boolean
    Dim ret As Boolean = False
    Dim c As Integer = 0
    Dim dr As Data.DataRow
    Dim n As String

    Try
        'Check for data
        If odr.HasRows Then
            Do While odr.Read()
                '(Re)Set c and declare new data row
                c = 0
                dr = d.DT.NewRow
                'n = ""

                'Iterate through the columns
                Do While c < odr.VisibleFieldCount
                    n = d.DT.Columns(c).ColumnName
                    'dr.Item(n) = odr.Item(n)
                    If n = "Pct_Of_CPU" Then
                        Dim t As String = odr.Item(c).GetType.ToString
                    End If
                    'n = n & odr.Item(c).ToString

                    dr.Item(c) = odr.Item(c).ToString
                    c = c + 1
                Loop

                'Add dr to the data table
                'd.DT.Rows.Add(dr)
            Loop

            'We've successfully read out all rows, update ret
            ret = True
        Else
            'Report the error
            Me.Errors.Text = "The data reader contained no data to populate the data table with." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
            Me.Refresh()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Errors.Text = "Encountered an error while attempting to capture the query data in a data table. Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Me.Errors.Text
        Me.Refresh()
    End Try

    Return ret
End Function
```

Comment: why are you calling Sum on a value being divided by 100 `sum(sessioncpu/100)` ? Also it looks like you are missing a parenthesis or have them out of order because simplyfied it reads as (x/y*z).

Comment: You could get rid of the 100s anyway. I don't think you have a (floating point) reason to divide by 100 and multiply again at the end.

Comment: Brandon, the Sum is there are there a multitude of jobs from the particular App_Type for that minute whose CPU use is being aggregated. The paratheses line up, though I could simplify the equation to SUM(cpu/100)/42840000. Shawn, the first 100 converts the value to a percentage (I think). In all honesty that bit of SQL is inherited from the guy that used to pull this data, and I'd rather not monkey with it if it's avoidable, just to make sure the data stays consistent.

Comment: Try putting in  `If c >= dr.ItemArray.Count Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index is larger than item array")` in before the `dr.Item(c) = odr.Item(c).ToString` bit.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't hit the ArguementOutOfRange line. That does makes sense though, the table is hard coded to have 4 columns added shortly after creation and when I'm hitting the error c = 2.